# Understanding Polkadot Communication Substreams

Tags: blockchain, substrate, libp2p

I'm trying to understand the steps of `/dot/block-announces/1` protocol selection. Firstly, a transport of nosie, yamux has to be created. A secure channel is opened, on top of that `ipfs/ping/1.0.0`, `ipfs/id/1.0.0` are selected & connection alive state information is exchanged(Periodically). How does transport upgrade to `/dot/block-announces/1` protocol from `ipfs/ping` protocol? Will block announce substream be closed once a block request is served ? When does Upgrade Select Error event happens? Correct me if I'm wrong but skipping handshake because it is not needed for block announce protocol.

[Spec Link](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-lite/blob/main/polkadot_re_spec.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear.

> How does transport upgrade to `/dot/block-announces/1` protocol from `ipfs/ping` protocol?

No such upgrade occurs.

> Will block announce substream be closed once a block request is served ?

No, block requests and announcements are decoupled.

If you do not have a specific question, but are just looking for a place to chat about Substrate and learn more, please join us in our technical chat https://app.element.io/#/room/!HzySYSaIhtyWrwiwEV:matrix.org